# How to use vl_covdet in Python

Tags: python, vlfeat

Can anybody tell me how i can use `vl_covdet` in python? Currently I am only using the sift provided by `vlfeat` but i am not getting the desired features through this method.

```
cmmd = str("/home/hassan/vlfeat/bin/glnxa64/sift "+imagename+" --output="+imageoutput+
        " "+params)
os.system(cmmd)
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you are asking how to use part of the [VLFeat library](http://www.vlfeat.org/). That site only lists Matlab, Octave, command line, and C interfaces. Technically, you could create a [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/) python interface using the C interface to the VLFeat library. But, that could be quite challenging if you are not well versed in C and python. If you're lucky, someone else has created one, but a few searches didn't reveal one to me.

Have you tried looking for python versions of the specific detectors? A [search for "sift"](https://www.google.com/search?q=scipy%20%22sift%22) returned multiple sites claiming a python implementation of SIFT (at least one of which was based on numpy/scipy which is the most commonly used python scientific library).